# Get imageview repeating: looks like titlebar

Tags: android, android-layout

i try to get this picture at the top of my app as an "titlebar".
So i want that it repeats itself. But i am a little bit stuck here.

[image]

I have this code in my background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/topbar"
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

and this is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/bgColor"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

....
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/topbar" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width of ImageView as `match_parent`. That will do it. But you can also do that with 9patch images. For more information check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

**EDIT**

Here is the layout with repeated background image. You need to set the src of ImageView as background.xml. And the reason there is a space between the image parent layout is that parent has padding. If you remove it, it will be fine as well.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sadly it doesn't work. It makes it a little wider, but not from the very left to the very right. And idk why, but there is space between the image and the top border.

Comment: sadly this is what i get then: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-24855488/app.jpg.html

Comment: well, that works for me. You are probably doing something else there. Here is the Screenshot from my XML. [LINK](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-24855490/ss_repeat.png.html)

Comment: do i have to put the background.xml in every drawable-xxx directory?

Comment: hm ok i created a folder drawable, it didn't exist before. Here a full list of my layout http://pastebin.com/FRV7pNVN

Comment: I cannot test this. You need to create a new XML file and paste the code in my answer. That should work.

Comment: ok, i tried your code. i deleted mine and pasted yours. It still doesn't work. Maybe my backgroud.xml is wrong?

Comment: Your background xml seems correct."topbar" in background.xml  should be the png image. There is no reason that It cannot work.

Comment: Steps are easy, - you need to have ImageView match_parent, - src of the ImageView should be the "background", not the source image itself.

Comment: @progNewFag come to chat, it's getting messy here.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62639/discussion-between-osayilgan-and-prognewfag